# Use CoreData For First iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-applications, core-data

Im in the midst of making my first iPhone app.  Much of the UI is finished so most of what I have left is database stuff.

It is a simple gym log app and I want users to be able to see their data online. Whether or not it will be editable or read-only via the web portal is determined on how difficult it would be to implement.'

I currently have all exercises stored in a plist that is loaded into a table.  I want to have user accounts (registrations) and basic profile views etc.  Most data I need to snyc and store will be NSStrings and NSDate and NS int etc, nothing too custom.

Will CoreData fit my needs?  And if I use CoreData, can I make my web portal via HTML/CSS and use MySQL or SQLite to sync?

I'm very new to database stuff and I'm going to read Apple's CoreData documentation tonight.

Comment: Adam Eberbach is correct according yo me. But better would be using JSON than XML because it will help you in many of your future apps as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Core Data for your app because Core Data is not a database system but rather an object graph management system for creating the model layer of a Model-View-Controller design app (and the Apple API pretty much requires that design pattern.)

The model layer is the actual guts of the program. It is where the actual logic central to the utility of the app gets done. Everything else is just an interface to the user, servers or other apps.

For example, in your app, your model layer will model of simulate some kind of  real-world objects, events or conditions related to a gym workout e.g. workout times, schedules, reps, exercise series etc. All the ***logical*** relationships in between these real-world things will be encoded in the data model and no where else. Core Data makes that simple to implement.

Once the data model is configured, then all you have to do to finish the app is to slap on one or more interfaces. In your case, it sounds like you want an UI on the device, a JSON interface to a server somewhere and possibly an http server within the app itself running over Wifi. If your data model is already completely configured, implementing each interface becomes trivial and, most importantly, changes made in one interface are instantly reflected in all the others.

So, it's good to learn Core Data. In fact it is good to master it. It will let you simply churn out the apps once you become skilled.

However, having said all that, don't let the pursuit of an elegant/perfect design get in the way of shipping. Your code can be inelegant and butt ugly and still succeed if you users never suffer for it. Beautiful code that just sits on the developer's drive benefits no one. Make it work with what you know now and get it out the door. You can always refractor later.

Core Data does have a learning curve precisely because it is so powerful. If you plan on doing a lot of apps you should take the time to learn it but, again, don't let the learning curve get in the way of shipping.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to read up on Apple's documentation on CoreData tonight and see how it goes.  If I use CoreData, everything will be there right? Like no need for separate .plists etc?  And I can implement JSON snyc like @Adam Eberbach said in his answer?  And I'm thinking that using CoreData will make my simple data structure too complex.

Comment: It depends. I find myself using Core Data for things that I used to put into arrays, dictionaries or custom objects. Once you master it, it just becomes easier to use than anything else. Core Data simplifies interaction with the UI and other interfaces. But all that requires getting to really know it. Like I said, don't let learning Core Data get in the way of shipping. If you apps works, it's simple and all you need to do is graft on a simple JSON interface then don't bother with Core Data for this versions. Refractor it later into Core Data if needed.

Comment: I would add that Core Data is intended to handle complexity i.e. complex data with complex behaviors. If you have simple data without any behaviors and little modification, then you don't need Core Data especially if you face a learning curve to get. You want to learn it long term but don't let that get in the way of shipping an otherwise workable app.

Comment: Thanks TechZen, Im definitely going to look into learning CoreData, but for the first version of my app, I think I'm going to stick with something more simple so I can get it to market ASAP.  I'm still having trouble figuring out how to go about the data process though.  So far I have all the exercises and muscles in a plist and they load perfectly to their tables.  I need a way to have the user edit a custom routine consisting of these exercises and probably save that data to another plist.

Comment: Plist are simply collection objects e.g. arrays, dictionaries,etc that are written to disk using the `writeToFile:` method. You can create an arbitrarily complex data structure by nesting arrays, dictionaries and sets as needed.  So, you might have each custom workout saved as a dictionary and save a series of workout dictionaries to an array and then write the array to disk. However, to be used the entire structure has to be read into memory at once so there is an upper limit to how much data you can practically store this way. Core Data was implemented in part to get around that limitation

Answer (score 4):

Core Data is great for storing data on your device but looks like you want to sync data to a web service. You should definitely not try and send Core Data objects (i.e. .sqlite files) back and forth. Look into JSON, there are a few libraries available but I have used json-framework by Stig Brautaset and it is a great library.

Turning your data into a JSON string for transmission to a web service is easy as long as you can first put it into an array or a dictionary. Receiving JSON data is even easier since the JSON parser creates objects such as arrays and dictionaries for you which you can then access in the normal way.

XML is another alternative but I don't think it is as easy to work with due to the libraries available not being as great as the JSON libraries.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Your response really helped me. Any particular sites or tutorials I should look into?

Comment: This is not a bad tutorial, though a bit old: http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/